# Is there a more efficient way of adding or removing a css class depending on a checkbox state?

Tags: jquery, dry, performance

Is there a more efficient, DRYer way of writing the if-else-statement in following piece of code? It just doesn't look nice.

```
var $diffPaymentAddressFieldset = $('fieldset.diffPaymentAddress', 'form.myForm');

// $checkbox is an input with type=checkbox
if ($checkbox.is(':checked') === true) { 
    $diffPaymentAddressFieldset.removeClass('hidden');
} else {
    $diffPaymentAddressFieldset.addClass('hidden');
}
```

(FYI: Ignore the long variable names, they'll get minified.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `toggleClass()`

```
$diffPaymentAddressFieldset.toggleClass('hidden', $checkbox.is(':checked'));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I forgot toggleClass had that switch parameter.

Comment: anyway, if the checkbox is sibling of the fieldset you could hide it with plain CSS on newer browser

Answer (score 0):

Or a one-liner with addClass/removeClass ?

```
$diffPaymentAddressFieldset[$checkbox.is(':checked')?'removeClass':'addClass']('hidden');
```

Also, for gods sake try to use shorter variable names ?

Comment: My variables get minified either way and I rather use long descriptive variable names than adding comments.

Comment: Do whatever you like, there won't be a problem with production code anyway, if you minify it both comments and names will be removed/shortened, but in my opinion it's just easier to read/write code where the variable names aren't 26 letters ?